# custom css rule is not applied

Tags: html, css, devextreme

for my project I use some external css from devextreme. Now, I would like to override some rules. For this I inspected the external css and found the class to override. I use the css files like this:

```
    <link href="~/css/devextreme/dx.greenmist.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/css/customized.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

In the customized.css I change a property:

```css
.dx-treeview-toggle-item-visibility {
    font: 14px/1 DXIcons;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #333;
    width: 21px;
    height: 32px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px; /*new property instead of left: -4px*/
}
```

If I run the app, I see, that the topmost rule is this customized rule, but there is the original rule too and my customized rule isn't applied (see the picture):

[image: css rule order]

Why is my custom css rule not applied?

Comment: it is applied... right and left are different properties

Comment: because you're not overwriting it, you need to set `left: auto` to your CSS rule. rules are incremental, new one won't completely overwrite old one if you not specify which rules to be overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`left` and `right` are two different properties. Try to add:

```css
left: auto;
```

to your custom style.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I thought, if I don't define the left property, it won't be applied.

Comment: @derstauner Nope, all existing rules are applied, unless you override them.